# Rails 3 ActiveRecord #size Method Bug After Upgrade to Ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, upgrade

An application I work on is using Rails 3.2.18 and Active Record 3.2.18. It was using Ruby 2.0.0, but someone from DevOps needed to upgrade to Ruby 2.2.4 today. Once users started making traffic on the site, everything started to explode. The administrators can't even access Active Admin.

After digging into this for quite some time, I realized I was thrown off by an error I was constantly seeing:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Since some of my models have a `name` attribute, I assumed this was the culprit.

Long story short, the issue is with calling `size` on an Active Record `has_many` relation that has not yet been loaded into memory. Here is how I can demonstrate this in Rails' console:

```
model_instance = MyModel.find(12345)
model_instance.some_relations.size
# the error from above will be thrown (nomethoderror on name: for nil)
model_instance.some_relations
model_instance.some_relations.size
# it works fine and produces expected output
```

Also, `model_instance.some_relations.count` will always work (though I do understand the differences between `count` and `size`).

I have found surprisingly little on this issue. There is a related [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/380), but I can't prove it's the *same* issue I am having.

I am going to rollback my release which upgrades to Ruby 2.2.4 for now, but was wondering if anyone can shed some light on this. Is there a bug between Active Record 3.2.18 and Ruby 2.2.* ? Is the only solution, assuming I need to upgrade to Ruby 2.2.4, to upgrade Rails as well?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18991#issuecomment-74886210

Comment: you should try and move to rails 3-2 stable and see if the issue is still there.  also, there are subtle differences for size/count, why do you want size here?

Comment: Im amazed at how many SO users post answers in the comments ;). I had no choice or involvement in the decisions for this particular application. Im something like the 8th developer to be contracted to work on it, and just dove into this problem today :). Also, Id hardly call "in memory else db query" vs "always db query" to be a *subtle* difference, in fact, it is probably the *major* difference which drove the original developers to choose `size` over `count`.

Comment: also thanks for the help @spickermann and @ Anthony, that Github issue was surprisingly hard to find via websearch for me (perhaps cuz it was so old). I just happened to find it about the same time your comments were posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a conflict between Rails 3.2.18 (and a few other patch versions) and Ruby 2.2.*. It is documented [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18991).

Aside from updating to a supported version of Rails, which may not be viable solution for some production applications, the Rails version could be updated to branch: `3-2-stable`.